# Full outer join with "case when" and subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, join, subquery, outer-join

I have a full outer join query with case when and sub query in oracle. What I am trying to accomplish is aggregating current year data and previous year data from the same table in order to compare them. However my FULL OUTER JOIN is acting as an inner join not returning the null values from both the current year and the previous year.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT
   SQ1.CHANNEL,
   SQ1.SHORT,
   SQ1.NAME,
   SQ1.RDC,
   SQ1.CY_APPROVED_COUNT,
   SQ2.PY_APPROVED_COUNT,
   SQ1.CY_APPROVED_VOLUME,
   SQ2.PY_APPROVED_VOLUME,
   SQ1.CY_DECLINED_COUNT,
   SQ2.PY_DECLINED_COUNT,
   SQ1.CY_DECLINED_VOLUME,
   SQ2.PY_DECLINED_VOLUME,
   SQ1.CY_RETURNED_COUNT,
   SQ2.PY_RETURNED_COUNT,
   SQ1.CY_RETURNED_VOLUME,
   SQ2.PY_RETURNED_VOLUME
FROM ( SELECT 
          CHANNEL,
          SHORT,
          NAME,
          RDC,
          SUM (CASE WHEN STATUS = 'Approved' THEN  APP_COUNTS ELSE 0 END) AS CY_APPROVED_COUNT,
          SUM (CASE WHEN STATUS = 'Approved' THEN  PROJ_VOL ELSE 0 END) AS CY_APPROVED_VOLUME,
          SUM (CASE WHEN STATUS = 'Declined' THEN  APP_COUNTS ELSE 0 END) AS CY_DECLINED_COUNT,
          SUM (CASE WHEN STATUS = 'Declined' THEN  PROJ_VOL ELSE 0 END) AS CY_DECLINED_VOLUME,
          SUM (CASE WHEN STATUS = 'Returned' THEN  APP_COUNTS ELSE 0 END) AS CY_RETURNED_COUNT,
          SUM (CASE WHEN STATUS = 'Returned' THEN  PROJ_VOL ELSE 0 END) AS CY_RETURNED_VOLUME
       FROM WFRT_MSP_SP_MTD
       WHERE PERIOD >= TO_DATE('2016/02/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
         AND PERIOD <= TO_DATE('2016/02/13','yyyy/mm/dd')
         AND CHANNEL = 'MSP'
         AND RDC = 'BASE'
       GROUP BY 
          CHANNEL,
          SHORT,
          NAME,
          RDC 
) SQ1
-- NOT CORRECTLY SHOWING NULL VALUES
FULL OUTER JOIN  

( SELECT 
     CHANNEL,
     SHORT,
     NAME,
     RDC,
     SUM (CASE WHEN STATUS = 'Approved' THEN  APP_COUNTS ELSE 0 END) AS PY_APPROVED_COUNT,
     SUM (CASE WHEN STATUS = 'Approved' THEN  PROJ_VOL ELSE 0 END) AS PY_APPROVED_VOLUME,
     SUM (CASE WHEN STATUS = 'Declined' THEN  APP_COUNTS ELSE 0 END) AS PY_DECLINED_COUNT,
     SUM (CASE WHEN STATUS = 'Declined' THEN  PROJ_VOL ELSE 0 END) AS PY_DECLINED_VOLUME,
     SUM (CASE WHEN STATUS = 'Returned' THEN  APP_COUNTS ELSE 0 END) AS PY_RETURNED_COUNT,
     SUM (CASE WHEN STATUS = 'Returned' THEN  PROJ_VOL ELSE 0 END) AS PY_RETURNED_VOLUME
FROM WFRT_MSP_SP_MTD
WHERE PERIOD >= TO_DATE('2015/02/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
   AND PERIOD <= TO_DATE('2015/02/13','yyyy/mm/dd')
   AND CHANNEL = 'MSP'
   AND RDC = 'BASE'
GROUP BY 
   CHANNEL,
   SHORT,
   NAME,
   RDC
) SQ2
ON sq1.short = sq2.short
;
```

Please help if you can.

Comment: Might help to use some indentation for readability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT CHANNEL, SHORT, NAME, RDC,
       SUM(CASE WHEN this_year = 1 AND STATUS = 'Approved' THEN  APP_COUNTS ELSE 0 END) AS CY_APPROVED_COUNT,
       SUM(CASE WHEN this_year = 1 AND STATUS = 'Approved' THEN  PROJ_VOL ELSE 0 END) AS cY_APPROVED_VOLUME,
       SUM(CASE WHEN this_year = 1 AND STATUS = 'Declined' THEN  APP_COUNTS ELSE 0 END) AS CY_DECLINED_COUNT,
       SUM(CASE WHEN this_year = 1 AND STATUS = 'Declined' THEN  PROJ_VOL ELSE 0 END) AS CY_DECLINED_VOLUME,
       SUM(CASE WHEN this_year = 1 AND STATUS = 'Returned' THEN  APP_COUNTS ELSE 0 END) AS CY_RETURNED_COUNT,
       SUM(CASE WHEN this_year = 1 AND STATUS = 'Returned' THEN  PROJ_VOL ELSE 0 END) AS CY_RETURNED_VOLUME,
       SUM(CASE WHEN prev_year = 1 AND STATUS = 'Approved' THEN  APP_COUNTS ELSE 0 END) AS PY_APPROVED_COUNT,
       SUM(CASE WHEN prev_year = 1 AND STATUS = 'Approved' THEN  PROJ_VOL ELSE 0 END) AS PY_APPROVED_VOLUME,
       SUM(CASE WHEN prev_year = 1 AND STATUS = 'Declined' THEN  APP_COUNTS ELSE 0 END) AS PY_DECLINED_COUNT,
       SUM(CASE WHEN prev_year = 1 AND STATUS = 'Declined' THEN  PROJ_VOL ELSE 0 END) AS PY_DECLINED_VOLUME,
       SUM(CASE WHEN prev_year = 1 AND STATUS = 'Returned' THEN  APP_COUNTS ELSE 0 END) AS PY_RETURNED_COUNT,
       SUM(CASE WHEN prev_year = 1 AND STATUS = 'Returned' THEN  PROJ_VOL ELSE 0 END) AS PY_RETURNED_VOLUME
FROM (SELECT msm.*,
             (CASE WHEN PERIOD >= DATE '2015-02-01' AND
                        PERIOD <= '2015-02-13'
                   THEN 1 ELSE 0
              END) as prev_year,
             (CASE WHEN PERIOD >= DATE '2016-02-01' AND
                        PERIOD <= '2016-02-13'
                   THEN 1 ELSE 0
              END) as this_year
      FROM WFRT_MSP_SP_MTD msm
     ) msm
WHERE CHANNEL = 'MSP' AND RDC = 'BASE'
GROUP BY CHANNEL, SHORT, NAME, RDC;
```

Comment: I'm getting ORA-00904: "MSM": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: @dmoses simply move the `msm` alias from just outside the subquery's close bracket, to inside it (i.e. you need to alias the table inside the subquery, not the subquery itself).

Comment: @Boneist I moved the "msm" right next to the table in the sub query "wfrt_msp_sp_mtd" and recieved error message "literal does not match format string"

Comment: @dmoses seems like the DATE literal keyword was accidentally missed off a couple of the date literals; make sure `PERIOD <= '...` becomes `PERIOD <= DATE '...`